# One Scroll Bar for three option or select areas

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I want to implement three `<select>...</select>` areas or `<option>...</option>` areas, controlled with one scroll box, that should be looking like

```
|-------|  |-------|  |-------| /\ 
|  aas  |  |  aas2 |  |  sdj3 |  | 
|  asd  |  |  asd2 |  | werh3 |  |
|  qwd  |  |  qwd2 |  | qwe3  |  | 
|-------|  |-------|  |-------| \/
```

Is it possible to create a separate scroll bar, and how do I implement it?

Should i use jquery and javascript or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

yes of course :
 look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/freealone/eEhky/3/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a bit of css.
Just place the three elements in a div with a class e.g. .main and add this css:

```
.main {
 max-height: 100px; //or whatever you want
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Take a look at the [css overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property

I think this is the easiest solution to what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/g3UWu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make one container div with a specified height and CSS overflow:scroll; and put those three areas (as divs) inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do. There is one question do you want to multiple selection? I make that example. Is it what you want? When you select item it turns red and selects a checkbox. It is pure js

http://jsfiddle.net/boralp/qQD7U/7/

Answer (score 0):

I had found a nice way how to scroll the table, for that it is necessary include table into  wrapper, and for wrapper apply following style:

```
.scroll_wrapper{
  float:left;
  overflow:auto;
  height:266px;    <-- some custom height
  width:100%;
}
```

This works well for IE and Mozilla browsers.

So i just create wrapped table with 3 columns instead of creating table using div tags....

But suggestions are really work anyway.

Answer (score -1):

try the 15  best jquery scrollbar here

http://slodive.com/web-development/jquery-scroll/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  All you are doing here is sending the OP somewhere else to read about a *possible* solution...